# Reading Tehillim on Klaf

Tags: sources-mekorot, tehilim-psalms, segulah

Anyone know of a source to read Tehillim from Klaf? I have heard it's something more special than reading from a regular sefer.

Comment: What do you mean by "more special"?

Comment: dani, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! You could make this question stronger if you [edit] in more information about where and what you've heard about this practice. I hope you also look around and find other information here of interest, perhaps starting with our 95 other [tag:tehilim-psalms] questions. Finally, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: It would seem that the Steipler was a strong adherent of this view although no real  reason is brought why? See this website - https://tehillimonklaftefilah.org/why-tehillim-on-klaf/

Comment: Also here https://winners-auctions.com/en/items/complete-book-of-tehillim-on-parchment-20th-century/ where it writes "The virtue of reciting Tehillim from parchment is well-known. Sar HaTorah Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky is particular to have a parchment Tehillim at his study hall, and he himself reads from it. This demonstrates the magnitude of the virtue in reading Tehillim from parchment, and he said that this tradition is from his father, the author of Kehillot Ya’akov ."